# Introducing a dummy argument via STL or Boost

Tags: c++, boost, stl

Suppose one wants to fill a vector with random numbers. Then there is a following obvious solution:

```
vector<int> result;
result.resize(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    result[i] = generateRandomNumber();
}
```

OK, it obviously works, but I would like to understand what is the simplest STL/Boost way to get rid of the for loop. It is tempting to use std::transform, but it takes a function with one argument. Is there any nice STL way to introduce a dummy argument in a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard library has `std::generate()` and `std::generate_n()`;

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
int generateRandomNumber()
{
    return std::rand();
}
int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    std::vector<int> result;
    generate_n(back_inserter(result), n, generateRandomNumber);
    copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

test: https://ideone.com/5xD6P

As for the second question, if I understand it correctly, is how to create a functor that takes an int argument, ignores it, and calls your `int f()`?

C++98 way is to actually write the whole functor:

```
struct IgnoreArgument
{
    typedef int(*fp_t)();
    fp_t fp;
    IgnoreArgument(fp_t f) : fp(f) {}
    int operator()(int) const { return fp(); }
};
...
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), IgnoreArgument(f));
```

test: https://ideone.com/DTsyl

C++11 way is to use a lambda expression

```
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), [](int){return f();});
```

test: https://ideone.com/nAPXI

And the C++98/boost way is to use `boost::bind`

```
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), boost::bind(f));
```

test: https://ideone.com/cvd88

Comment: Thank you greatly. But the question about dummy variable is still open.

Comment: @Ilya Razenshteyn Could you give an example of how such variable would be used?

Comment: Suppose I have a function int f(), now I want to produce a function int g(int) { return f(); } using standard things.

Comment: Why not `generate_n(back_inserter(result), n, std::rand);` ?

Comment: @Rob OP had `generateRandomNumber()`, I only gave it sample content to have a compilable example.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might be something more subtle.

Answer (score 1):

Use `generate_n` with how many elements you want, along with a `back_insert_iterator` to the vector where you want them stored, and a pointer to the function that generates the numbers.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int generateRandomNumber()
{
    static int i = 0;
    return 42 + (i++);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vi;
    std::generate_n(back_inserter(vi), 10, &generateRandomNumber);    
}
```

Note that by using the `back_insert_iterator` as I do here, you do not have to pre-size the vector, which is kludgy at best.

Comment: @Ilya:  Then replace the `back_inserter` in my example with `.begin()`

Comment: Thank you, but, again, the question about dummy variable is still open. It would be great to find it out.

Comment: @Ilya:  Maybe I don't understand the question then?  What dummy variable?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `transform` just isn't the right choice for the task at hand. The intent of `transform` is to take some inputs, transform each in some prescribed way, and produce an output for each of those inputs.

In this case, you don't *have* any inputs. `transform` would make sense if the values in the vector were based (somehow or other) in values in some existing vector.

`generate_n` is really the right solution to the problem -- it's intended to invoke some function/functor N times, producing N results, and assigning those to the output iterator (and its successors) that you supply. Since it's intended to generate values (rather than transforming existing values) the function/functor doesn't take an input, and you don't have to provide "fake" input.

As far as the "dummy" argument goes, wanting/needing it is probably a pretty good sign that (as in this case) you're using the wrong algorithm, and just shouldn't do that.

You do, however, sometimes get into the reverse situation: you want to use an algorithm that *doesn't* supply an argument, but you want to be able to supply an argument. For example, let's assume you wanted to be able to set the numbers in your array to a random number, with some lower and/or upper bound specified by the user. In this case, you want to be able to specify the bound(s) that'll be passed to your random number function, but neither `generate` nor `generate_n` has any provision for doing so.

In this case, you have two possibilities. One is `bind` (originally `boost::bind`, but now included in C++11). What I prefer as a rule is to use a functor, and I pass the argument(s) to the ctor:

```
class gen_random { 
    int lower;
    int upper;
public:
    gen_random(int lower = 0, int upper = RAND_MAX) : lower(lower), upper(upper) {}

    int operator() { return rand_range(lower, upper);
};

int main() { 
    std::vector<int> rand_ints;

    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(rand_ints), 10, gen_random(1, 6));
    return 0;
}
```